# Entity Framework - Binding WPF Tree view control

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework

[image]

In Service Category table, ParentCategoryId is the ServiceCategoryId and that is the parent category, there can be nth level hierarchy of my categories, so I need to present this using Tree View Control.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Hierarchical DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx)

HTH