# How can I create a Hierarchical data template using tree view?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchical-data, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm using a class created from entity frameworks (Categories table in database)

And only contains three fields:

- CategoryID
- CategoryName
- ParentCategory

And entity framework created me two navigation: Subcategories and Parent

And when I load the collection in a treeview, it show me everything, where it should only show the top levels.

I think I should create a hierarquical data template, but I really have no idea about creating it.

EDIT: It similars these case: [Entity Framework - Binding WPF Tree view control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501611/entity-framework-binding-wpf-tree-view-control)

My control XAML contains:

```
<TreeView x:Name="objectiveTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Objectives}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Subcategories}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CategoryName}"
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: I accidentally the whole title

Comment: It is [a meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-accidentally), but never mind.

Comment: H.B.Please check the last message

Comment: Doesn't the template work? It looks fine, or is your only problem that is left that all elements are in the root list?

Comment: @Darf, I think your problem here was that you did not bind your TreeView ItemsSource to a collection that only has the "top-most" parent items. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3598656/1751090) for an example of how to collect only the top-level parents. Your navigation down from those parents binding to entity navigation properties looks good. Hope you ended up getting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

Code-behind:

```
objectiveTree.ItemsSource = (List<YourMainEntity>) _entities;
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="objectiveTree">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Subcategories}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParentCategory}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>                        
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}"  ItemContainerStyle="
    {StaticResource Level1}">
   <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
   <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"  
   ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Level3}">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />        
   </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    </TreeView>
```

---